# Get the count of Checked check box using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to get the count of checked check Boxes form below code sample,
[image]

Thnks,
Digambar K.

Comment: please post the html instead of image

Comment: actual code is much nicer than an image. Or a link to the code?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please post the actual code in 'code' tags, so this will appear in search results and can be of help for future people looking for the same issue.

Also, a little googling would have found you the answer right away:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to count all checkboxes from a page?

If yes:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
```

If you want to count just checkbox inside the table:

```
$('table input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    alert($('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length)   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and stupid!

Try something like this:

```
// count all checkboxes
var count = $(":checkbox").length();

// count all checkboxes checked
var countChecked = $(":checkbox:checked").length();
```

Answer (score 0):

Will give you all the checked inputs inside the table

```
$('.ms-input input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
```